# How to find the branch points

Tags: complex-analysis

$w=\operatorname{sech}^{-1}z$ satisfies $\frac{1}{\cosh w}=z$. Prove $\operatorname{sech}^{-1}z=\log\left(\frac{1+(1-z^2)^{1/2}}{z}\right)$ and find the location of its branch points

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{Derivation}$: Let $y = sech(x)= \frac{2}{e^x+e^{-x}}$. Interchange $x,y$ to solve for inverse. Then, $y = \frac{2}{e^x+e^{-x}} = \frac{2}{e^x+\frac{1}{e^x}}$. Let $e^x = z>1, x>0 \Rightarrow y=\frac{2}{z+\frac{1}{z}} \Rightarrow y = \frac{2z}{z^2+1} \Rightarrow z^2y-2z+y=0$. This quadratic gives: $z=\frac{1 +/- \sqrt{1-y^2}}{y}$. Since $z=e^x>1 \Rightarrow $ choose $z = \frac{1+\sqrt{1-y^2}}{y}>1$. Lastly, interchange $x,y$ to get: $sech^{-1}(x) = \ln(\frac{1+\sqrt{1-x^2}}{x})$.

$\textbf{Branch point}$: Set $\frac{1+(1-z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}}{z}=0 \Rightarrow 1+(1-z^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}=0 \Rightarrow 1-z^2 = 1 \Rightarrow z^2=0 \Rightarrow z =0$